# How is it that a struct containing ValueTuple can satisfy unmanaged constraints, but ValueTuple itself cannot?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, unmanaged, c#-7.3

Consider the following types:

- `(int, int)` → managed.
- `struct MyStruct { public (int,int) Value; }` → unmanaged!

**Problem:** A non-generic structure `MyStruct`, which has a managed member `(int,int)` has been evaluated as managed type.

**Expected Behavior:** A structure which contains a managed member, should be considered as managed, the same way the `struct MyStruct { int? Value; }` are considered as managed.

It seems both types are behaving against the documentations [[1]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#unmanaged-constraint) and [[2]](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/65b8af18a97ff37cae4835b7715c426e81142152/proposals/csharp-7.3/blittable.md#detailed-design).

**Example 1 - unmanaged Constraint**

```
class Program
{
    static void DoSomething<T>() where T : unmanaged { }
    struct MyStruct {  public (int, int) Value; }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DoSomething<MyStruct>();    // → OK
        DoSomething<(int, int)>();  // → Shows compile-time error
    }
}
```

> Error CS8377  The type '(int, int)' must be a non-nullable value type,
>   along with all fields at any level of nesting, in order to use it as
>   parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Program.DoSomething()'

**Example 2 - pointer or sizeof**

Using above structure, the behavior is the same for [pointers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/pointer-types?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) or [`sizeof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/sizeof?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) operator:

```
unsafe 
{
    (int, int)* p1;  // → Compile-time error, 
    MyStruct* p2;    // → Compiles
}
```

> Error CS0208 Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a
>   pointer to a managed type('(int, int)')

**Question**

1. How do a struct containing `ValueTuple` is considered as `unmanaged` and can satisfy `unmanaged` constraint while the `ValueTuple` is considered as managed?
2. How a struct having `ValueTupple<T1, T2>` and a struct containing `Nullable<T>` are treated differently?

---

<sub>**Note 1:** IMO the issue is different from the [Proposal: Unmanaged constructed types](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1504) (addressed by DavidG in comments), because `MyStruct` is not generic, on the other hand while `int?` and `(int,int)` both are managed, but `struct MyStruct { int? Value; }` and `struct MyStruct { (int, int) Value; }` evaluated differently.</sub>

Comment: Yeah, but that issue is about unmanaged constructed type, and I guess tuples fall into that same bracket.

Comment: Well, I read that issue as a bug in the compiler that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Fun fact: Resharper sees this first line (`DoSomething<MyStruct>()`) as the same error.

Comment: Of course it's a different issue, I just thought it was interesting to share.

Comment: I believe this is a compiler error. I'd recommend opening an issue on the Rosyln repo

Comment: Was my comment here linking to the Github issue really flagged and deleted?

Comment: @DavidG Feel free to post your comment again if you think it's required. I removed my comments as well since they are no longer required.

Comment: I'm less bothered that they were flagged, more concerned that a mod decided it was valid to be removed.

Comment: Especially since I still believe it's the same issue that you are experiencing.

Comment: @DavidG I agree about your point about flagging. But disagree about being the same issue (while they are related and may have the same root cause.) Flagging was done by me because based on your comment '*Of course it's a different issue, I just thought it was interesting to share.*' I thought we are agreed about begin a different issue and so these comments are no longer needed. Probably moderator also had the same understanding as me. Anyway, I'm sorry if it offended you, it was not intentional, it was a misunderstanding.

Comment: @DavidG If for any reason you would like to post the comment again, let's clean up the comments and post your comment again. I appreciate your input about the question.

Comment: I've summarized question(s) at the bottom of the post.

Comment: My "different issue" comment was saying that the Resharper issue is different from what you were asking in your post. I'm not offended, just a little uncomfortable that a moderator would remove comments that potentially provide valid information.

Comment: As for why I still think it's the same issue, a tuple is a constructed type (`(int, int)` is the same as `ValueTuple<int, int>`) and why I think the bug in the compiler is picking up the *root* type as being constructed. Speculation of course, but I'd be surprised if you opened an issue and it didn't get closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @DavidG I see, probably they had the same misunderstanding and like me they also thought we no longer need it. Anyway, at the bottom of the post I mentioned your comment.

Comment: @DavidG The compiler is using different rules for a struct having `int?` field and a struct having `(int, int)` fields, while both of them are generic structs. Maybe because `int?` is special *nullable* struct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. This is just a bug in the compiler. The tuple when used as a field should be registering as a generic type and hence invalid in an `unmanaged type`. It appears to be evaluating as a tulpe instead and missing this check.

Good news is that in C# 8.0 this restriction will be going away. The type `(int, int)` is a valid `unmanaged type`.

Comment: Thanks!  *It appears to be evaluating as a `Tuple` ...* → Do you mean evaluated as a `non-generic struct`? because if it's evaluating as `Tuple/ValueTuple`, since they are managed types, then `struct MyStruct { (int,int) Value; }` should be evaluated as `managed` while it's been evaluated as `unmanaged`.