# stuck with generic type constraint

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

Say i have two generic methods:

```cs
int GetValue<T>() where T: unmanaged
{}

int GetAnotherValue<T>()
{}
```

I need to forward a call to one of those methods like this:

```cs
void Init<T>()
{
    int i;
    //here is my problem
    if( T is unmanaged)
        i = GetValue<T>();
    else
        i = GetAnotherValue<T>();
}
```

I do not figure how to dispatch the call based on the generic type T.
Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: What's the context here? Why are you doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if a type fits the unmanaged constraint in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53968920/how-do-i-check-if-a-type-fits-the-unmanaged-constraint-in-c)

Comment: static unsafe int SizeOf<T>() where T: unmanaged => sizeof(T);
static int GetSize<T>() => is unmanaged ? SizeOf<T> : IntPtr.Size; //here is my pb.

Comment: Not sure where you are going with that code, but it's probably incorrect. If you are trying to find the size for interop: A type which is not `unmanaged` is not `IntPtr.Size` big, it depends on what the marshaller is doing. You could just use `Marshal.SizeOf` anyway. And if you want the *managed* size, you can just use `sizeof` either way.

Comment: I need to allocate an array based on a generic type T. if T is managed then the size of each item is the size of a reference (IntPtr.Size) otherwise T is a struct and i have to call SizeOf<T>. Marshal.SizeOf do not accept generic parameter.

Comment: @dzAdel I can't think of a legitimate reason why you would be doing that...

Comment: "if T is managed then the size of each item is the size of a reference (IntPtr.Size)" not sure where you get that from: if it's not `unmanaged` it might still be a `struct` and not that size. Furthermore, newer versions of `Marshal.SizeOf` *do* take a generic parameter, and even on older versions, you can just do `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T))`. And I also see no reason why you would do this: if you are trying to marshal it manually, you need to know the exact type anyway